# Challenges in Rewriting java code in PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL file with a procedure that only contains Java code.

Following is the declaration before the Java code begins:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "fnd_log_file_handler" AS
```

This Java code performs various File manipulation (copy, check length, iterate over an array of files, check if a File object is a directory, etc) and DOM manipulation/XML parsing (create XML Document object from a given XML String). Additionally, it is also calling an external command using the Runtime.exec() java method that returns a Process object. Following are the packages imported:

```
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

There is also one method that is invoked repeatedly. It returns list of files in a folder matching particular name pattern. It uses Comparator to filter the results. Following is an excerpt of the code

```
/**
     * This API returns list of files in a folder matching particular name pattern.
     * @param path - Path to the directory to get list of files
     * @param pattern - Pattern for file names to look for. All files with name 
     * starting with this pattern will be returned from the API
     * @return - Sorted list of files. 
     */

  private static File[ ] listFilesInOrder (String path, String pattern, 
                                        Comparator <File> compareFunc) 
  {
      BASEFILENAME = pattern;
      File lFile = new File (path);

      File[] arrayFileList = lFile.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
          public boolean accept(File f, String s) { return s.startsWith(BASEFILENAME + INDEX_SPERATOR); }
      });


      if(arrayFileList!=null)
      {
        Arrays.sort(arrayFileList, compareFunc);

      }

      return arrayFileList;
  }
```

I am looking to remove java dependency in case JVM gets removed from the DB in the future. Is it possible to write PL/SQL code to include all this logic? If not, what are my other options? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: In case JVM gets removed from the DB in the future?

Comment: @Kayaman Java is an optional component in Oracle databases and it is unfortunately quit common for DBAs to remove it.  It's stupid, but it happens, so it's wise to try to avoid a Java dependency when possible.

Comment: @JonHeller Is there a work around for situations like this? Can this code still exists as an independent Java file that can be invoked from within the DB? I am not sure if it's even feasible to translate all this logic in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in PL/SQL. To work with files in file system you need to look at Oralce UTL_FILE package see: [Oracle UTL_FILE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF)

To work similarly with lists in java you can use your custom TYPE and TABLE of that TYPE in your PL/SQL code.

PL/SQL is powerful enough to do such logic

Comment: I'm familiar with the URL_FILE package. Is there a way to invoke an external application  and DOM manipulation?

Comment: Definitely it is possible to invoke external application and XML manipulations are possible as long as Oracle has XPath/XQuery ability. Sorry, for now I'm too far from PL/SQL to tell exactly how... you can just dig through documentation. It is not hidden too dip...  good luck :)